# Python Memory error during function return statement

Tags: python, regex, memory

Hi i am processing a 600Mb file. i have written the below code. What i am doing was, to search for a keyword in the data between  `<dest>` tags and if it exists then add a city tag to `<dest>` tag. It worked fine for small set of data but when i ran the program on large file it is throwing MEMORY ERROR. I guess i am getting this error when i use return statement in `if condition` can any one please let me know how to solve this?

```
import re

def casp ( tx ):
    def tbcnv( st ):
        ct = ''
        prt = re.compile(r"(?i)(Slip Copy,.*?\))", re.DOTALL|re.M)
        val = re.search(prt, st)
        try:
            ct = val.group(1)
            if re.search(r"(?i)alaska", ct):
                jval = "Alaska"
                print jval
                if jval:
                    prt = re.compile(r"(?i)(.*?<dest.*?>)", re.DOTALL|re.M)
                    vl = re.sub(prt, "\\1\n" +  "<city>" + jval + "</city>" + "\n" ,st)
                    return vl
                else:
                    return st
            else:
                return st
        except:
            print "Not available"
            return st   

    pt = re.compile("(?i)(<dest.*?</dest>)", re.DOTALL|re.M)
    t = re.sub(pt, lambda m: tbcnv(m.group(1)), tx)
    return t

with open('input.txt', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
    pt = re.compile(r"(?i)<Lrlevel level='3'>(.*?)</Lrlevel>", re.DOTALL|re.M)
    content = re.sub(pt,lambda m: "<Lrlevel level='3'>" + casp(m.group(1) + "</Lrlevel>" ), content)

with open('out.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write(content)
```

Comment: I'm guessing that running a regex on a 600M file could be a reason for your memory error...

Comment: Read the file line by line, `read()` will put the whole file into memory at once which might be causing this error.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary  i need to capture date between two tags which are in multiple lines.

Comment: is this an `xml` file? If so, use a proper iterative parser like `lxml.etree.iterparse`

Comment: You guess you are getting this error when you use `return` statement...  Can you provide more data about why you suspect this??  I seems unlikely a priori.

Comment: @ArminRigo When i remove the return statement which is above except the code is not throwing any memory error but data is missing.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the `return` statement just before the `expect`, then the string built by `re.sub()` is much smaller.

I'm getting memory usage that is 3 times the file size, which means that you'd get a MemoryError if you don't have (more than) 2GB.  This is reasonable here --- or at least I can guess why.  It's how `re.sub()` works.

This means that you're using somehow the wrong tools, as explained in the comments above.  You should either use a full xml-processing tool like lxml, or if you want to stick with regular expressions, find a way to never need the whole string in memory; or at least to never call `re.sub()` on it (e.g. only the `tx` variable ever contains a big string, which is the input; and you do `pt.search(tx, startpos)` in a loop, locating the places to change, and writing piece by piece parts of `tx`).